# ByteBuffer underflow

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I try to use the java libary ByteBuffer and wrote following code example:

```
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
    buf.putInt(4);
    buf.putInt(8);
    buf.putInt(12);
    buf.putInt(16);
    buf.putInt(20);
    buf.putInt(24);
    buf.putInt(28);
    buf.putInt(32);
    buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    byte[] temp = new byte[32];
    buf.get(temp);
```

For some reason it throws a [BufferUnderflowException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/BufferUnderflowException.html) in the last line.

I don't know why, can somebody explain me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in java docs

> Relative get method. 
>   ...
>
> Throws:
>   BufferUnderflowException If the buffer's current position is not smaller than its limit

Find more [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/nio/ByteBuffer.java)

Comment: yes - and maybe add that `putInt` automatically increments the position

Comment: Thanks the command buf.position(0); before buf.get(temp); solved it!

Comment: buffer 当前的位置，不小于它的限制值。也就类似indexoutofbound

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://mindprod.com/jgloss/bytebuffer.html

You must call ByteBuffer.flip to convert from filling the buffer via physical I/O to emptying it via ByteBuffer.get